# Droplet Applescript Touch

Tags: terminal, finder, applescript

i was trying the last days to get a droplet working, which is changing the time stamp of every dropped .jpg / .tif / .dsc / .cr2 to the actual time or even a few secs earlier in Terminal.

Would appreciate if anyone could help me.

Greetings
TiRa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Automator to [create your droplet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3087148/how-to-make-a-droplet-on-mac-osx-with-automator). The process of updating a file's time stamp is called `touch`; this superuser question explains more, [How can I “touch” a file from the Mac UI?](https://superuser.com/questions/428452/how-can-i-touch-a-file-from-the-mac-ui)

1. Launch Automator.app
2. Create a new workflow
3. Add a **Run Shell Script** action
4. Set **Pass input:** to **as arguments**
5. Within the script, replace `echo` with `touch`
6. Save your workflow as an application

[image: Automator touch]

To learn more about using Automator, see Apple's [Mac Basics: Automator](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2488).